# 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command with salesforce cli

Tags: lightning, community, lightning-web-components

I'm getting started with the Lightning Web Components and chose trailheads to get the insight into the basics. 
I am working on **Push and Deploy Lightning Web Component Files** of the LWC basics module.

It requires installing e-bikes using the Saleforce DX.

A step here involves cloning the app using the below command:

**git clone https://github.com/trailheadapps/ebikes-lwc**

However, this leads to the following error:

> 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

I have native git installed on my desktop and I'm not sure how to resolve this even after spending hours on the same thing .

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: By "native Git", do you mean GitHub Desktop? What specific package did you install?

Comment: @DavidReed.. Yes by native Git I mean Github desktop.

Answer (score 6):

[GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) is a distribution of Git that comes with a graphical user interface. It provides much of the same functionality as command-line Git, but if you wish to use this product to complete Trailhead modules, you'll need to translate the commands provided for use in the CLI into actions in the GitHub Desktop UI.

GitHub provides [instructions](https://help.github.com/en/desktop/contributing-to-projects/cloning-a-repository-from-github-to-github-desktop) on how to clone a repository using GitHub Desktop.

If you want to use the CLI version of Git, you'll need to make sure it is installed and configured appropriately for your OS. The main [Git website](https://git-scm.com/) is a good starting point that will provide download links for your OS. Note that while working with command-line Git, you'll have to take care of either authenticating with your username and password or setting up SSH, and you'll have to make sure (or your chosen installer will) that Git is in your PATH. GitHub Desktop abstracts those facets for you.

Comment: To echo @David Reed it sounds like you just have Git desktop installed but not git itself. 
f you type git -- version from your command line you will get the version currently installed.